# Upgraded Ubuntu, Lost Years of Firefox Files

Tags: upgrade, firefox, bookmarks

Upgraded to Ubuntu 21.10 (from 21.04 I think, didn't write it down).  Now years of work, e.g., hundreds of Firefox bookmarks, passwords & logins seem to be gone.

No, I did not use Sync, nor did Ubuntu or Firefox encourage me to use Sync before the upgrade.

Those files must be on my computer, just with a deleted registry.  Please, please, please help.

Comment: --> `~/.mozilla/firefox/XXXXX.default/` ?

Comment: How do you know they are lost? I suspect the `.mozilla` folder is still in the home dir, and Firefox is a snap now. Also, if you really don't want to lose them, make a backup.

Comment: Your bookmarks are all there. Sign back into your mozilla account they should all appear as before.

Comment: Work around : Install google  chromium-browser, and import bookmarks etc. . .........  Then Firefox can import from Chromium : File → Import From Another Browser. ..... If not complete with the "snap chromium" replace snap package with https://www.google.com/chrome/?platform=linux ............ Make backup : `tar cf moz_Oct-17-2021.tar .mozilla` .... ..... ! Make backups frequently !